# How can I zoom/rotate view while I use brush select?

Tags: 3d-view, selection-tools

How can I zoom or rotate view while I use brush select (<kbd>c</kbd>)? Because scrolling adjusts brush size and the middle mouse button deselects, respectively

Comment: I think you can't. Unless you have a 3Dmouse I guess.